# legends on ggvis graph are overlaping when using tooltip

Tags: r, ggvis

I'm generating a graph with `ggvis` and the legends are in top of each-other.

```
library(ggvis)
df1 <- data.frame(x=c(0.6,1,1.4), y=c(-2, -.8, -0.2), number=c(10,8,6), 
                  type=c('A', 'A', 'B'))
df1 %>% ggvis(x = ~x, y = ~y) %>% 
  layer_points(shape=~type, fill=~number)
```

[image]

How can I fix this?

Thanks!

---

Steven's solution works for the simple example but It does not work when you add a tooltip:

```
library(ggvis)
df1 <- data.frame(x=c(0.6,1,1.4), y=c(-2, -.8, -0.2), number=c(10,8,6), 
                  type=c('A', 'A', 'B'), id=c(1:3))

tooltip <- function(x) {
  if(is.null(x)) return(NULL)
  row <- df1[df1$id == x$id, ]
  paste0(names(row), ": ", format(row), collapse = "<br />")
}

df1 %>% ggvis(x = ~x, y = ~y) %>% 
  layer_points(shape=~type, fill=~number, key := ~id)  %>% 
  add_tooltip(tooltip, "hover") %>%
  add_legend("shape", properties = legend_props(legend = list(y = 50)))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
df1 %>% ggvis(x = ~x, y = ~y) %>% 
  layer_points(shape=~type, fill=~number) %>%
  add_legend("shape", properties = legend_props(legend = list(y = 50)))
```

[image]

---

**Edit:**

As mentionned by @aosmith, you could use the `set_options()` workaround:

```
df1 %>% ggvis(x = ~x, y = ~y) %>% 
  layer_points(shape=~type, fill=~number, key := ~id)  %>% 
  add_tooltip(tooltip, "hover") %>%
  add_legend("shape", properties = legend_props(legend = list(y = 50))) %>%
  set_options(duration = 0)
```

Comment: This solution does not work when you have a tooltip :( I just added that example. Thanks!

Comment: @Ignacio Adding `set_options(duration = 0)` to the end of the pipe might help with the addition of the tooltip.  See the conversation at [github issue #125](https://github.com/rstudio/ggvis/issues/125).

Comment: @aosmith I was actually reading the same issue when you posted your comment. Still early days for `ggvis` ;)