# User specified fill

Tags: r, if-statement, shiny, ggvis

I am using ggvis and have the following code with a selectInput on the UI side allowing the user to select which variable dictates fill and shape (inputId is fill and shape respectively).  I want the plot to have the ability to have a constant fill or shape should the user choose.  The else section of this code works exactly how I want, but when I select the option in the if statement the app crashes with the following error:

```
Error in eval: could not find function ":="
```

I know I have the syntax correct because if I suppress the legends and the if/else statement and specify the fill as constant (fill := "black") it works how I want it to.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
vis <- reactive({
fillvar <- prop("fill", as.symbol(input$fill))
shapevar <- prop("shape", as.symbol(input$shape))
filteredData() %>%
ggvis(x = xvar, y = yvar) %>%
  layer_points(size.hover := 200,
               fillOpacity:= 0.5, fillOpacity.hover := 1,

               # Allows for points to be consistent if the user desires

               if (input$fill == "All Points Black") {
                 fill := "black"}
               else {
                 fill = fillvar}
               ,

               if (input$shape == "All Points Circles") {
                 shape := "circle"}
               else {
                 shape = shapevar}
              ,

               key := ~ID
  ) %>%

  # Adds legends to the Plot in designated locations
  add_legend("fill", title = as.character(fillvar)) %>%
  add_legend("shape", title = as.character(shapevar), properties = legend_props(legend = list(y=300))) %>%

  # Adds the previously defined tool_tip my_tooltip
  add_tooltip(my_tooltip, "hover") %>%

  # Specifies the size of the plot
  set_options(width = 800, height = 400, duration = 0)
})

#Actually plots the data
vis %>% bind_shiny("plot1")
```

Comment: If you can extract the if/else logic before the ggvis statement to two variables, then it should work.

Comment: @warmoverflow This did not work.  If I place the if else statements outside ggvis, it still gives the same error when the constant option is selected.

Comment: You might try your logic outside ggvis and also before using `prop`.  Make a variable that is either the mapping variable, `as.name(input$fill)` OR `"black"` based on your logic.  Pass this new variable to `prop` within `layer_points`, e.g., `prop("fill", newvar)` and avoid `:=` all together.

Comment: @aosmith I figured out how to make the code function as I want if I suppress the legend.  However, if the data visualization is set to anything other than the user specified "All Points Black"  or "All Points Circles" I still want the legend to display.  Any input on this? I am adding a revision to my original post to reflect the updated code.

Comment: The legend is added if the `fillvar` is a variable and not added if `fillvar` is a constant, so you don't need `add_legend` at all.  If it's not working (maybe because you have two legends?), try adding a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) to your question so folks can take a look at things.  Also, rather than updating your question you can write an answer showing how you solved your problem and ask a new question for a new problem.

Comment: @aosmith Yes I do have two legends (fill and shape) and they overlap when I do not specify add_legend.

I will take your suggestion into account for the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in a comment, you can create a variable for `prop` using an `if` statement.  This allows you to bypass the issue of `:=` by using either a constant or a variable directly in `prop`.

You get legends automatically.  To control the placement when you have two legends (which will lead to an overlap), you can name your `ggvis` graph.  This allows you to refer to add elements to the graphic in order to move the second legend down only when it is added based on logic and your `shapevar` and `fillvar` values.

Here's the code just for the reactive function.

```
vis <- reactive({
    fillvar = "black"
    if(input$fill != "All Points Black") {
        fillvar = as.name(input$fill)
    }

    shapevar = "circle"
    if(input$shape != "All Points Circles") {
        shapevar = as.name(input$shape)
    }

    p1 = filteredData() %>%
        ggvis(x = xvar, y = yvar) %>%
        layer_points(size.hover := 200,
                   fillOpacity:= 0.5, fillOpacity.hover := 1,
                   prop("fill", fillvar),
                   prop("shape", shapevar),
                   key := ~ID
        ) %>%

        # Adds the previously defined tool_tip my_tooltip
        add_tooltip(my_tooltip, "hover") %>%

        # Specifies the size of the plot
        set_options(width = 800, height = 400, duration = 0)


    # Control addition of second legend using if() on p1 object
    if(fillvar != "black" & shapevar != "circle") {
        p1 %>% add_legend("shape", properties = legend_props(legend = list(y=300)))
    }
    else {
        p1
    }

})
```

Answer (score 0):

The code now is functional with input from @aosmith as I want it to be if the legend is suppressed. However, when I do this, the legend for fill and shape overlap as this post addresses.

[legends on ggvis graph are overlaping when using tooltip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30916337/legends-on-ggvis-graph-are-overlaping-when-using-tooltip/)

The fix for that is to add in a legend which makes the plot disappear if the constant data visualization option is selected.  I will post a new question to try and get this issue resolved.

UPDATE: The answer below solves the original issue, but @aosmith's answer fixed a second issue that arose after correcting the first issue as well.

My code with the corrected original issue, but containing an overlapping legend (corrected with @aosmith's answer) is below.

```
vis <- reactive({

  # Allows for points to be consistent if the user desires
  if (input$fill == "All Points Black") {
    fillvar = "black"}
  else {
    fillvar <- as.symbol(input$fill)}

  if (input$shape == "All Points Circles") {
    shapevar = "circle"}
  else {
    shapevar <- as.symbol(input$shape)}

#Plot Data with Visualization Customization
xvar <- prop("x", as.symbol(input$x))
yvar <- prop("y", as.symbol(input$y))

filteredData() %>%
  ggvis(x = xvar, y = yvar) %>%
  layer_points(size.hover := 200,
               fillOpacity:= 0.5, fillOpacity.hover := 1,
               prop("fill", fillvar),
               prop("shape", shapevar),
               key := ~Shot_ID
  ) %>%

  # Adds the previously defined tool_tip my_tooltip
  add_tooltip(my_tooltip, "hover") %>%

  # Specifies the size of the plot
  set_options(width = 800, height = 450, duration = 0)
})

#Actually plots the data
vis %>% bind_shiny("plot1")
```